# Exporting PowerShell Foreach Loop to HTML

Tags: html, powershell, export

I've been trying to write a script that pings a list of computers from a text file and exports the output to a HTML file.

Using a ForEach loop and and if/else statement I have been able to get a working ping script working that displays in PowerShell but haven't been able to export the results to a html file.

When I run the script the HTML file opens but only displays the line "Here are the ping results for $date"

I'm pretty new to PowerShell so any kind of input or help would be appreciated!

```
$ComputersAry = Get-Content -Path "C:\Script\ping.txt"
$filepath = "C:\Script\"
$date = "{0:yyy_MM_dd-HH_mm}" -f (get-date)
$file = $filepath + "Results_" + $date + ".htm"
New-Item $filepath -type directory -force -Verbose 

$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;background-color: #6495ED;}
TD {border-width: 1px;padding: 3px;border-style: solid;border-color: black;}
</style>
<title>
LRS Ping Results
</title>
"@

Foreach ($MachineName in $ComputersAry) { 

    $PingStatus = Gwmi Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address ='$MachineName'" | Select-Object StatusCode

        if($PingStatus.StatusCode -eq 0){
        $output = write-host "$MachineName,Ping Success!!,$Date" 
        } else {
        $output = write-host "$MachineName,Ping FAIL, please investigate cause ASAP!!" 
        } 

    }


$pre= "Here are the ping results for $date"

$output | Select-Object Name, Status, Date | ConvertTo-HTML -Head $Header -PreContent $pre | Out-File $file

Invoke-Item $file
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing gets assigned to `$output` when you use `Write-Host`.  Try this instead:

```
$output = "$MachineName,Ping Success!!,$Date" 
...
$output = "$MachineName,Ping FAIL, please investigate cause ASAP!!"
```

`Write-Host` tells PowerShell to write directly to the host's display.  This bypasses the Output (stdout) stream. While you could replace `Write-Host` with `Write-Output` almost no one uses `Write-Output` because the default stream every goes to is the output stream anyway.  So when a string like "Hello World" reaches the end of the pipeline and there isn't an Out-File or Out-Printer it will by default get stuck into the Output stream and when the result of the pipeline execution is assigned to a variable, it gets whatever is in the output stream.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the following, save the code as a script and run it.

```
PS C:\Scripts> .\Demo.ps1 | ConvertTo-Html | Out-File C:\Scripts\out.htm

$result = '' | Select Online
$ComputersAry = GC C:\Scripts\2.txt
Foreach ($MachineName in $ComputersAry) { 

 $PingStatus = Gwmi Win32_PingStatus -Filter "Address ='$MachineName'" | Select-Object StatusCode

 if($PingStatus.StatusCode -eq 0){
   $result.Online = "$MachineName,Ping Success!!" 
  } else {
   $result.Online = "$MachineName,Ping FAIL, please investigate cause ASAP!!" 
  }
   $result
  }
```